# DDD - Performing simple operations on complex Aggregates

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

I'm reading the DDD blue book and there is one thing that's pretty unclear to me as of yet and that is how to efficiently perform simple operations on Aggregates that have a lot of child Entities in them.

#### An example

- Considering I have an `Order`, (Aggregate Root) that has `Line Item`s.
- Each `Order` can only have 1000 `Line Item`s. (Business Rule).

#### Steps

In order for me to add a `Line Item` to the `Order` I'd have to:

- Reconstitute the `Order` with **all** it's `Line Item`s from it's repository.

  - `orderRepo.getById(1)`
- Add the `Line Item` to the `Order`,

  - `order.addLineItem(lineItem)`
- Save the `Order` via the repository again.

  - `orderRepo.save(order)`

Unless I'm missing something, this strikes me as terribly innefficient. What if I have 900 `Line Items` on that `Order`? I'd have to load a lot of data from the DB to perform this simple operation.

Yes, I could lazy load the `LineItems` but even then I won't be able to check the business rule that requires that <1000 `Line Items` must exist in an `Order`, unless all the `Line Items` are loaded.

Also, lazy loading implementations strike me as an anti-pattern because they usually tie the property accessors with repositories.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a method to your repository called `GetOrderItemsCount()`,  pass it the ID of the order you are interested in, and return the number of items currently in the order.  This will satisfy your business rule, and you can optimize it any way you want.
2. You don't have to load all of the existing items in an order to add a new one, especially if you already know the current count and have checked it against your business rule.
3. Lazy loading?  What lazy loading?

Answer (score 2):

When using DDD, you compromise performance for better domain model. And this is an area where that compromise might be made.

Looking at your problem, I would question of `LineItem` should be part of `Order` aggregate. The point of aggregate is to group entities that multiple, complex operations are made on. Imagine you have an aggregate with internal entity and 10 operations. In one case, 9 of the operations work on the entities. In such a case, it would drastically complicate the situation if the entities weren't always loaded. If on the other hand only 1 of the operations need those entities, then I would question if those entities should be part of the aggregate. In case of complexity of the operations, your case is relatively simple. Taking count of items is trivial operation, that can be done on DB side. But imagine if the limit was for price and not for count. In this case, you have to run complex "price calculation" logic, which will probably require all order items with all the data. Meaning, you cannot afford not loading line items.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is you thinking you need to hold actual `Item` objects in your `Order` aggregate. That is wrong. If you were to do this, the memory footprint would really be insane and performance would be awful. And you should not do it, because a single operation (a command) should only affect one aggregate. This makes your code more cohesive and concise at the same time.

To stay much more performant and consistent, in reality the `LineItem` is a very simple object holding just references to identifiers of both `Order` and `Item`.

```
final class LineItem {

    private final OrderId orderId;

    private final ItemId itemId;

    public LineItem(OrderId orderId, ItemId itemId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.itemId  = itemId;
    }
}
```

and adding an `Item` to your `Order` aggregate would be modeled as follows:

```
public class Order {

    private static final int MAX_CAPACITY = 1000;

    private final OrderId orderId;

    private final List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        if (lineItems.size() == MAX_CAPACITY) {
            // throw exception
        }

        lineItems.add(new LineItem(orderId, item.itemId()));
    }
}
```

If you are wondering how you're going to read data from this the answer is you do not have to and usually do not. Aggregates can grow in size but that's in favor of keeping your business rules consistent and visible. For reads and performance you will need a different layer talking to a database directly, completely circumventing the aggregates. You can do this because you know that all data in the database HAS to be valid, because all modifications are made through aggregates protecting the rules.

Another option to solving this issue is having the `GetItemsCount(OrderId)` in `OrderRepository`, as others have already suggested. Still, I believe your main problem is thinking about referencing aggregates incorrectly.

If you're looking at a very good source for aggregate modeling, definitely look at [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838) by Mr. Vaugh Vernon.

Answer (score 1):

In DDD you need to load the entire Aggregate from the repository before you apply a command to it. If you think that you don't need to load it entirely then your Aggregate boundary may be wrong, you could have an Aggregate that is too big. Remember, Aggregates are the transactional boundary: every thing that happens inside an Aggregate is safe from concurrent updates, the operations are strong consistent. This *safe-ness* is nice but costly and thus must be done according to the real-world business.

> Also, lazy loading implementations strike me as an anti-pattern because they usually tie the property accessors with repositories.

Yes, in the Aggregate design context, Lazy-loading is an anti-pattern. It means that your Aggregate boundary is wrong (most probable).

> Each Order can only have 1000 Line Items. (Business Rule).

That is the maximum but you need to also consider the average case where an `order` have an average `line item` count of what, `5`?

Yes, for a large `order` adding a `line item` will be slower but how often does it happen?

Also, you cannot protect this business rule by querying the repository for the `line item` count and check against the number `1000`! This query+checking operation is eventual consistent (two line item could be added at the same time when there are 999 items in the order)!